# when using delete join pop out E_US09C4 Syntax error on line 1

Tags: sql, ingres, vectorwise

I am using Vector Version VW 4.2.2. When I use delete join, one error pop out,
E_US09C4 Syntax error on line 1.
Could anyone help solve this? Thanks very much.
Below is my sql script:

```
delete T.* from table1 T
join table2 F
    on T.collective_Id = F.portfolio_id
    and T.activity_Year = F.activity_Year
    and T.activity_month = F.activity_month
```

Comment: ... and what is the error?

Comment: sorry, error is E_US09C4 Syntax error on line 1.  Last symbol read was: 'T'.

Comment: This syntax is a MySQL extension to ANSI SQL. It may not exist in other databases.

Comment: maybe it is. Thanks. But do anyone know the ingres syntax about this logic?

Comment: This issue has been resolved, please see below resolution:delete T.* from table1 T where exists (select 1 from (select id from table2 F) temp where temp.id = T.id)